# Can an application for a PhD after an undergraduate program be considered for MS if the profile fits it better?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters, statement-of-purpose

I am applying for a PhD under a professor whose interests strongly match with mine and I don't want to lose an opportunity to work with her. My profile is not so strong for a PhD as compared to a Master's program.

I want to know if letting the Admissions Committee or Professor know that I would accept the Master's program if they find me better suited for that will work. If yes, then which of these two should I inform and through which channel, SOP or e-mail?

I know this might vary in universities and the best way is to directly ask them, but I would like to know if this even happens in some US universities or not.

What I feel is that there are two extremes to this:

- The applicant is not clear with which program is right for him
- The applicant is dedicated to study/work with our professor

I don't know on where in between these two sides will the university place me upon reading my e-mail/application.

Comment: This question seems too closely related to your other question here (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/118352/should-i-mention-a-professors-name-in-my-sop-for-msc-if-the-professor-is-only-t) to really be a separate question. A light edit there will get you answers for this as well.

Comment: I completely agree! However, the problem is that both the questions are equally important to me and I won't be able to fit them in a balanced way in a 150 character title limit. I didn't want to lose people who could answer my question but didn't because they didn't want to answer the primary question mentioned in the title.